# In loop when save data get error next iteration not saving data Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, frameworks, entity

```
Foreach(var data in List)
{
    try
    {
        Genservice.save(data)   
    }
    catch(exception e)
    {
       Var message = e.Message;
    }
}
```

Exception occur when data save for First iteration.
Exception also occur when data save for second iteration.
But second iterate data was error free.
When checks exception it shows first iterate data exception story

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to describe.  The code shown won't compile, which means this isn't the actual code you're using to replicate the problem.  As for the problem, what is the exception?  What specifically is failing and why don't you expect it to fail?

Comment: Your code is invalid (Var is not a keyword, it's var).  It sounds like you are getting an exception the first time, but not the second time, but your code is only capturing the first exception.   I think you need to post your actual code.